# Android apk. Can it include the source code too?

Tags: android, apk

Is it possible to include the source code of the android application in the apk itself??
I mean the src folder, can it be a part of apk when installed on a debugdevice

Answer (score 3):

You could copy the src files into the assets folder.

Just curious: Why are you trying to do this?